# Is there a way to lock bootstrap so it doesn't stack columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I suffer from poor eyesight and I need a way to zoom in on a web page without it stacking and breaking. Is there a way I can lock bootstrap during development?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable zooming capabilities on mobile devices by adding user-scalable=no to the viewport meta tag. This disables zooming, meaning users are only able to scroll, and results in your site feeling a bit more like a native application.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```